# style is not working in variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

here two textboxes are not aligned center..so i want to give margin-left to that textbox..but that textboxes are coming dynamically from javascript..

Here is my code:

```
<table class="table" id="table1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="padding-left: 115px;">No of tables</th>
            <th>
                <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                No of person
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="success">
            <td style="padding-left: 145px;">
                1
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control uniform-input text" required="true">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="error">
            <td style="padding-left: 145px;">
                2
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control uniform-input text" required="true">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        :
        <tr class="info">
            <td style="padding-left: 145px;">
                7
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control uniform-input text" required="true">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<button class="btn btn-primary" href="#" onclick="addRow();">Add More</button>
</div>
</div>
```

JAVAscript :: Function Addrow()::

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var i=1;
function addRow()
{
  var tbl = document.getElementById('table1');
  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
  var iteration = lastRow - 1;
  var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);
  var firstCell = row.insertCell(0);
  var secondCell = row.insertCell(1);
  var el = document.createElement('input');
  var e2 = document.createElement('input');

  el.type = 'text';
  el.name = 'name_' + i;
  el.id = 'name_' + i;
  el.size = 15;

  el.maxlength = 15;

  firstCell.appendChild(el);

  e2.type = 'text';


  e2.name = 'name_' + i;
  e2.id = 'name_' + i;
  e2.size = 15;
  e2.maxlength = 15;

  secondCell.appendChild(e2);

 // alert(i);
  i++;
  frm.h.value=i;
//  alert(i);
 }
 </script>
```

I already tried `e1.style.marginLeft="88px";` and also tried to create one class , give margin-left in that class but It also not working..Please help me..
Again I want to say th problem: to give margin that textbox which create dynamically from javascript....Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var el = document.createElement('input');
var e2 = document.createElement('input');
e1.style.cssText = "margin-left:xx";
e2.style.cssText= "margin-left:xx";
```

else

```
var el = document.createElement('input');
var e2 = document.createElement('input');
e1.className = "dyn-tb";
e2.className = "dyn-tb";
```

and in css

```
.dyn-tb {
margin-left: xx;
}
```

Comment: Error: Uncaught Reference Error:e1 is not defined in javascript

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking something like this? As you have not provided your css, this code sample might not have the same look and feel but, the idea is to align the dynamic textboxes.

```js
var i=1;
function addRow()
{
  var tbl = document.getElementById('table1');
  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
  var iteration = lastRow - 1;
  var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);
  var firstCell = row.insertCell(0);
  var secondCell = row.insertCell(1);
  var el = document.createElement('input');
  var e2 = document.createElement('input');

  el.type = 'text';
  el.name = 'name_' + i;
  el.id = 'name_' + i;
  el.size = 15;
  el.className = 'right';

  el.maxlength = 15;

  firstCell.appendChild(el);

  e2.type = 'text';


  e2.name = 'name_' + i;
  e2.id = 'name_' + i;
  e2.size = 15;
  e2.maxlength = 15;

  secondCell.appendChild(e2);

 // alert(i);
  i++;
  frm.h.value=i;
//  alert(i);
 }
```

```css
.right{
  float:right;
  }
```

```html
<table class="table" id="table1">
                                         <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                               <th style="padding-left: 115px;">No of tables</th>
                                               <th>
                                                  <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                                                  No of person
                                               </th>
                                            </tr>
                                         </thead>
                                         <tbody>
                                            <tr class="success">
                                               <td style="padding-left: 145px;">
                                                  1
                                               </td>
                                               <td>
                                                  <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
                                                  <div class="col-lg-5">
                                                     <input type="text" class="form-control uniform-input text" required="true">
                                                  </div>
                                               </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="error">
                                               <td style="padding-left: 145px;">
                                                  2
                                               </td>
                                               <td>
                                                  <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
                                                  <div class="col-lg-5">
                                                     <input type="text" class="form-control uniform-input text" required="true">
                                                  </div>
                                               </td>
                                            </tr>
                                          :

                                            <tr class="info">
                                               <td style="padding-left: 145px;">
                                                  7
                                               </td>
                                               <td>
                                                  <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
                                                  <div class="col-lg-5">
                                                     <input type="text" class="form-control uniform-input text" required="true">
                                                  </div>
                                               </td>
                                            </tr>

                                         </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                   </div>
                                </div>
                                <br />

                                <br />
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" href="#" onclick="addRow();">Add More</button>
                             </div>

                             </div>
```

Comment: Error: Uncaught Reference Error:e1 is not defined in javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can set the css style property using
eg:

```
var el = document.createElement('input');
el.type = 'text';
el.name = 'name_' + i;
el.id = 'name_' + i;
el.size = 15;
el.maxlength = 15;
el.style.cssText = 'float:right;';
```

Comment: Error: Uncaught Reference Error:e1 is not defined in javascript

Comment: Change the e1 to el "el.style.cssText = 'float:right;';"

Comment: In the code you have posted it is 'el'. Please cross check you code.

Answer (score 1):

Add style to parent of your input "e1" :

```
firstCell.className = "centerContent"; 

.centerContent {
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: Error: Uncaught Reference Error:e1 is not defined in javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use `textAlign` property in `row` to align your input to `center`

like this

`row.style.textAlign = "center";`